# Live server traffic visualisation tools?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, traffic

What *live* server traffic visualisation tools are available for Apache (on Ubuntu Hardy LTS)?

It's for one site, rather than a full hosting environment, so I'm leaning towards ease of use and prettiness, rather than a long feature list :)

UPDATE: I'm mostly after after unique users/I.P.'s and server load (in order of preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after network stats, [ntop](http://www.ntop.org) provides a very nice interface for charting throughput, host connections, per-host network traffic, etc. I use it on a few routers and it introduces little load. It uses libpcap, so you can even tailor the filter if you want.

It doesn't monitor CPU usage, just network usage, but otherwise it sounds like it would fit most of your needs.

If you're looking for something you can install as an end-user, more akin to an AWstats type of setup, that's going to be a little more difficult as you'd have to constantly churn through logs. I do recall some PHP scripts that worked in conjunction with configuring Apache to pipe its access logs to a Perl or Python script that wrote them into a MySQL database at one point, but that might be more work than you're wanting and/or overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after live bytes in/out statistics, have a look at iptraf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for command-line tools try one of these:

```
jnettop
bmon
iftop
iptraf -i all
trafshow
dstat -N eth0,eth1,total
ifstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

What sort of stats are you looking to capture?  Bytes per second?  Number of 200/300/400/500 responses per second?  Unique IPs per second?

This link to the [Apache traffic stats](http://vuksan.com/linux/ganglia/#Apache_Traffic_Stats) can help you capture some of that data and get it into ganglia.  Assuming you have ganglia installed (and you should.)  I'm sure you can figure out how to modify this setup for many other things you'd like to capture.

Comment: Added more detail to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using `mod_status` with `ExtendedStatus On`?  It's surprisingly informative.

Answer (score 0):

You might find something of interest [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/88675/what-command-line-tools-for-monitoring-host-network-activity-on-linux-do-you-use/88681#88681) (no sense just reposting it in case I edit)